# is my new bluetooth keyboard ok

Tags: bluetooth, logitech-keyboard

i bought a logitech k780 keyboard a few months ago. i paired it to my laptop which has windows 10

i keep the bluetooth keyboard and the tv remote control on my bed during the day. the tv remote control has been gently dropped on top of the bluetooth keyboard a couple of times during the past few months

yesterday morning i pressed spacebar on the bluetooth keyboard to wake it from sleep and it pairs with my laptop. the windows start menu showed. that shouldn't happen. i pressed esc to close the start menu and i pressed the windows key on the bluetooth keyboard. the start menu showed

yesterday at night i pressed the windows key on the laptop keyboard. nothing happened. i double clicked on a txt file which is on the desktop. it opened but it showed behind the edit power options screen which i already had open. i clicked on the document and the text in it got erased because backspace was being pressed on its own. i switched off the bluetooth keyboard and i tried to type on the laptop keyboard. it worked. also the windows key worked again and the windows start menu showed. i wasnt using the bluetooth keyboard when the issue happened

why did these things happen?

is it a bluetooth connectivity issue or the keyboard circuits under the bluetooth keyboard buttons are starting to spoil?

i read the comments here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyWR1aI0yaM. i don't know. it looks like the keyboard has some issues

Comment: We can't on our site fix keyboard hardware problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that many other users are having similar issues, it's something with this specific keyboard.
Firstly I'd recommend checking for driver updates. Once all the drivers are up-to-date the problem could be fixed. If it doesn't work check here for more fixes in [this guide](https://windowsreport.com/bluetooth-keyboard-lag-fix/)

[On Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/logitech/comments/of0ozh/extreme_lagging_on_logitech_k780_keyboard_mx/) others are having similar problems and maybe it can help you as well.